# Make ripple that covers only part of a custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to make a custom View that looks like this:

[image: Text]

It acts like a Button when clicked. I want the ripple effect to only cover the rounded rectangle portion of the View, but I'm struggling to achieve this. Here's what the ripple looks like now:

https://youtu.be/mCR0C7QYrpU

Notice how the ripple goes all the way to the top, rather than stopping at the edges of the rounded rectangle. This is my first time making a custom View and I'm totally lost.

```
public class HeaderButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    Paint paint;
    float scaledUnit;
    RectF rectBounds;
    String text = "My text";

    public HeaderButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public HeaderButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public HeaderButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        float screenWidthPixel  = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        scaledUnit = screenWidthPixel * 0.001f;

        rectBounds = new RectF(3 * scaledUnit, 15 * scaledUnit, getWidth() - (3 * scaledUnit), getHeight() - (3 * scaledUnit));
    }



    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        float[] outerRadii = new float[8];
        Arrays.fill(outerRadii, 7 * scaledUnit);
        RoundRectShape shape = new RoundRectShape(outerRadii, null, null);
        ShapeDrawable mask = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
        ColorStateList stateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorError));
        setBackgroundDrawable(new RippleDrawable(stateList, null, mask));
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);
        float textStart = Math.round(getWidth() / 2.) - (textWidth / 2);
        float textEnd = Math.round(getWidth() / 2.) + (textWidth / 2);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        int scaledTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_button_label_text_size);
        paint.setTextSize(scaledTextSize);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));

        canvas.drawText(text, Math.round(getWidth() / 2.) - (textWidth / 2), 24 * scaledUnit, paint);

        // Removes the portion of the rounded rectangle that's behind the text.
        canvas.clipRect(textStart - (10 * scaledUnit), 0, textEnd + (10 * scaledUnit), 20, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorMainActivityBottomButtonBorderBackground));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3 * scaledUnit);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectBounds, 7 * scaledUnit, 7 * scaledUnit, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your `shape` into `LayerList` - in there, in XML at least, every `<item` tag may contain `padding` values

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp">

        <shape
            ...
    </item>
    <item ...
</layer-list>
```

didn't tried below, but programatically it may looks similar to this

```
ShapeDrawable mask = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
Drawable[] layers = {mask};
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
layerDrawable.setPadding(0, someValue, 0, 0);
ColorStateList stateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorError));
setBackgroundDrawable(new RippleDrawable(stateList, null, layerDrawable));
```

Comment: For some reason setting a top padding isn't having any effect, with or without the LayerDrawable. I tried setting top padding on the ShapeDrawable directly and that had no effect either.

Comment: well, now I don't have any other idea than splitting your custom view into two placed in `ViewGroup` and manage these inner `View`s padding. but your current approach is far better in terms of performance and clean-code, so I hope someone will post proper answer for curent code-base. good luck!

Comment: Actually I realized that setPadding() is pushing the view's actual content down rather than the ripple itself. I must be using it wrong somehow.

Comment: maybe you should put `RippleDrawable` in `LayerDrawable` with padding, not `mask`? (blind guess)

Comment: Nothing I do makes that ripple layer move at all. Thanks for the suggestions though. Setting a top padding works in XML, so it's weird that it's not working at all programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like trying to implement the ripple programmatically was a dead end. But I was able to figure out a solution that uses XML:

button_ripple.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorControlHighlight">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="8dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBackground"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

layout.xml:

```
... 

<myPackage.HeaderButton
        android:id="@+id/headerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter phone number"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_ripple"/>
...
```

HeaderButton.java:

```
public class HeaderButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    Paint paint;
    RectF rectBounds;
    String text = "My text";

    public HeaderButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public HeaderButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public HeaderButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // These measurements must exactly match the paddings you set in button_ripple.xml
        rectBounds = new RectF(dpToPx(3, getContext()), dpToPx(8, getContext()), getWidth() - (dpToPx(3, getContext())), getHeight() - (dpToPx(3, getContext())));
        isLayoutRequested();
    }


    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float textWidth = paint.measureText(text);
        float textStart = Math.round(getWidth() / 2.) - (textWidth / 2);
        float textEnd = Math.round(getWidth() / 2.) + (textWidth / 2);

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        int scaledTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_button_label_text_size);
        paint.setTextSize(scaledTextSize);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));

        canvas.drawText(text, Math.round(getWidth() / 2.) - (textWidth / 2), dpToPx(12, getContext()), paint);

        // Removes the portion of the rounded rectangle that's behind the text.
        canvas.clipRect(textStart - (dpToPx(7, getContext())), 0, textEnd + (dpToPx(7, getContext())), getHeight() / 2f, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorMainActivityBottomButtonBorderBackground));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(dpToPx(1.5f, getContext()));

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectBounds, dpToPx(3, getContext()), dpToPx(3, getContext()), paint);
    }
}
```

I initially tried this method and rejected it because it wasn't giving consistent results across all devices. But then I realized my `dpToPx()` method was different than the one Android uses internally. And this is important because the padding values you set in button_ripple.xml and HeaderButton.java must match perfectly. So make sure you're using this one:

```
    //Converts a dp measurement to a px measurement.
    public static int dpToPx(float dp, Context context) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```